# how does one call a function from a diffrent module in a thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm trying to create a multi threaded server using sockets. each user opens a new thread. this thread runs a function which eventually needs to call another function from a diffrent module, yet I always get a runtime error when it reaches the function it should call. any ideas?

```
    void Server::accept()
{
    // notice that we step out to the global namespace
    // for the resolution of the function accept

    // this accepts the client and create a specific socket from server to this client
    SOCKET client_socket = ::accept(_serverSocket, NULL, NULL);

    if (client_socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
        throw std::exception(__FUNCTION__);

    std::cout << "Client accepted. Server and client can speak" << std::endl;

    // the function that handle the conversation with the client

    std::thread lol(&Server::clientHandler, this, std::ref(client_socket));
    lol.detach();
}



void Server::clientHandler(SOCKET clientSocket)
{
    try
    {
        std::cout << "IM HERE";
        int userMessageType = 0;
        int sizeOfUserName = 0;
        int totalUserLen = 0;
        std::string loginReply = "";
        std::set<std::string> ::iterator itr;
        std::string allNames = "";
        while (userMessageType != MT_CLIENT_EXIT)
        {
            char buffer[2048];
            std::cout << "IM HERE";
            buffer[2047] = 0;
            std::cout << "IM HERE";
            userMessageType = Helper::getMessageTypeCode(clientSocket); // code crashes here!!
            std::cout << "ASDSAD";
            std::cout << "CODE " << userMessageType << std::endl;
            switch (userMessageType)
            {
            case MT_CLIENT_LOG_IN:
            {
                sizeOfUserName = Helper::getIntPartFromSocket(clientSocket, 2);
                std::string user = Helper::getStringPartFromSocket(clientSocket, sizeOfUserName);
                std::cout << user << std::endl;
                loginReply += "1010000000";
                for (itr = onlineUsers.begin(); itr != onlineUsers.end(); itr++)
                {
                    totalUserLen = totalUserLen + (int)(((*itr).length()));
                    allNames += *itr;
                    allNames += "&";
                    std::cout << "\n" << allNames << "\n";
                }
                if (totalUserLen != 0)
                {
                    std::cout << "ASD" << allNames.size();
                    allNames[allNames.size() - 1] = '\0';
                    std::cout << "ASD";
                    allNames = allNames.substr(0, allNames.size() - 1);
                    std::cout <<"\n" << allNames << "qqq";
                    for (int i = 0; i < 5 - allNames.length(); i++)
                    {

                    }
                    loginReply += std::to_string(allNames.length());
                    std::cout << loginReply;
                    Helper::sendData(clientSocket, loginReply);
                }
                else
                {
                    loginReply += "00000";
                    Helper::sendData(clientSocket, loginReply);
                    std::cout << "ASD";
                }
                onlineUsers.insert(user);
            }
            case MT_CLIENT_UPDATE:
            {
                std::string;
            }
            case MT_CLIENT_EXIT:
            {
                closesocket(clientSocket);
                return;
            }
            }
        }
        closesocket(clientSocket); 
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e)
    {
        closesocket(clientSocket);
    }


}
```

minimal reproductive example:
helper:

```
#include "Helper.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>

using std::string;

// recieves the type code of the message from socket (3 bytes)
// and returns the code. if no message found in the socket returns 0 (which means the client disconnected)
int Helper::getMessageTypeCode(SOCKET sc)
{
    char* s = getPartFromSocket(sc, 3);
    std::string msg(s);

    if (msg == "")
        return 0;

    int res = std::atoi(s);
    delete s;
    return  res;
}


void Helper::send_update_message_to_client(SOCKET sc, const string& file_content, const string& second_username, const string &all_users)
{
    //TRACE("all users: %s\n", all_users.c_str())
    const string code = std::to_string(MT_SERVER_UPDATE);
    const string current_file_size = getPaddedNumber(file_content.size(), 5);
    const string username_size = getPaddedNumber(second_username.size(), 2);
    const string all_users_size = getPaddedNumber(all_users.size(), 5);
    const string res = code + current_file_size + file_content + username_size + second_username + all_users_size + all_users;
    //TRACE("message: %s\n", res.c_str());
    sendData(sc, res);
}

// recieve data from socket according byteSize
// returns the data as int
int Helper::getIntPartFromSocket(SOCKET sc, int bytesNum)
{
    char* s = getPartFromSocket(sc, bytesNum, 0);
    return atoi(s);
}

// recieve data from socket according byteSize
// returns the data as string
string Helper::getStringPartFromSocket(SOCKET sc, int bytesNum)
{
    char* s = getPartFromSocket(sc, bytesNum, 0);
    string res(s);
    return res;
}

// return string after padding zeros if necessary
string Helper::getPaddedNumber(int num, int digits)
{
    std::ostringstream ostr;
    ostr << std::setw(digits) << std::setfill('0') << num;
    return ostr.str();

}

// recieve data from socket according byteSize
// this is private function
char* Helper::getPartFromSocket(SOCKET sc, int bytesNum)
{
    return getPartFromSocket(sc, bytesNum, 0);
}

char* Helper::getPartFromSocket(SOCKET sc, int bytesNum, int flags)
{
    if (bytesNum == 0)
    {
        return (char*)"";
    }

    char* data = new char[bytesNum + 1];
    int res = recv(sc, data, bytesNum, flags);

    if (res == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        std::string s = "Error while recieving from socket: ";
        s += std::to_string(sc);
        throw std::exception(s.c_str());
    }

    data[bytesNum] = 0;
    return data;
}

// send data to socket
// this is private function
void Helper::sendData(SOCKET sc, std::string message)
{
    const char* data = message.c_str();

    if (send(sc, data, message.size(), 0) == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        throw std::exception("Error while sending message to client");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `std::ref(client_socket)`? `Server::clientHandler` takes by value so there is no need for `std::ref` there.

Comment: Even worse, the `std::ref` will contain a 'reference' (actually, it is a pointer internally) to a local variable – which will be dangling as soon as you leave the function creating the thread.

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

`SOCKET` is a typedef to an integral type so you should replace `std::ref( client_socket )` part with `client_socket`.

Also thread accesses to `Server::clientHandler` are not syncronized. It is not a good solution but to prevent race-condition you might do the below.

```
void Server::clientHandler(SOCKET clientSocket)
{
     static std::mutex thread_safe;
      // Guarantees that only one thread proceeds at a time
     std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock { thread_safe };
     ....
     ....
```